# RoR Faker Information Not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I installed 'faker' gem but when I use it (Faker::Book.name) it doesn't display a random name, but only a string "Faker::Book"

lib > tasks > data_populate

```
require 'colorize'

namespace :data_populate do

namespace :populate do
    desc "Populate all model data set"
    task :all => :environment do
        require 'faker'
        puts "\n'Populating Model Data'".yellow
        Job.where(name: "Faker::Book").destroy_all
        10.times do |l|
            Job.create(name: Faker::Book.name, description: Faker::Lorem.sentence(7), business_id: 1)
        end
    end #all end
end #populate end
end #end rake dashboard
```

When the code runs, the Job Title is always "Faker::Book"

Comment: Did you try wrapping in curly brackets 

`Job.create(name: { Faker::Book.name } , description: { Faker::Lorem.sentence(7) }, business_id: 1)`

Comment: Just tried, gave me

syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
...eate(name: { Faker::Book.name }, description: { Faker::Lorem...

Comment: Well first of all `"Faker::Book"` is a literal string so that is never going to be evaluated unless you call eval on it. Secondly you can't use  `Job.where(name: Faker::Book)` - Faker::Book is a class - and calling the `name` or any of the other generator methods will generate a new unique value.

Comment: Max, I'm calling Faker::Book.name, but the return value is "Faker::Book", not a random value from the class call.

Comment: Just got it to work - there was a versioning issue -> I specified the correct latest version and reran bundle install. I think there might have been a change in a version regarding Book.name, Book.title, etc

Also, calling Faker::Book directly to populate db isnt a good method, so I assigned to local variable and used that variable to populate Job.create

Thanks all for quick morning responses!!!

Answer (score 0):

`"Faker::Book"` cant be stored to db, its name method just select a random name value, so it can't be also matched in `where` clause by class name, so you just try define some constance name part, and match over it:

```
Job.where("name LIKE 'faker%'").destroy_all
10.times do |l|
   Job.create(name: "faker " + Faker::Book.name, description: Faker::Lorem.sentence(7), business_id: 1)
end
```